# Hyperledger Composer `network install` is throwing `request timeout` error

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn) and found out that I am getting this error when I try:

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
```

---

**Error is:**

> ✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
>   Command failed

Any lead will be helpful.

**Update:**
`docker ps` output as follows:
[image]

Comment: can you add `docker ps` command output log in this question

Comment: @MaheshRajput done.

Comment: Its look like fabric network is running well but composer-cli can't get response from fabric network. 
can you try to restart fabric network by `./stopFabric.sh` and `./teardownFabric.sh` and start again by `./startFabric.sh` from fabric-dev-server  and try again network install command.

Answer (score 2):

To check your development environment, I would recommend follow the first tutorial composer example from https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.

If this works, you can replace logic.js, model.cto and permissions.acl file from your link.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. None of the Peers responded withing the given time. I edited the docker-compose.yaml file inside

> ~/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv12/composer

and added the following line

`- CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=1200s`

to the

> `peer0.org1.example.com` container environment.

Then I did a Teardown and re-executed the same steps. This time, it worked. You just need to increase the TIMEOUT from default `300s` to `1200s`. It happens when you do not have enough resources on your PC and the time to process the installation increases.